# Laravel logout and multiple tabs?

Tags: php, laravel, session, tabs

If I open my app from two tabs and log out from the first one (with `Session::flush();`, the second tab is still logged in on refresh. How to fix that?

I use Laravel 5.1 and Session driver - file.

Comment: To logout, use `Auth::logout()` See: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication#authenticating-users

Comment: you are using auth controller for the login and logout ?

Comment: I don't use auth controller, I have my own. I will try with Auth::logout(), thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do Auth::logout to completely logout the user.